# When writting a test for ffmpeg, how to write a makefile?

Tags: makefile, ffmpeg

Does anyone here know how to write a makefile for ffmpeg's test code?

Is the makefile maked by automake?

I found the demo's makefile, but not the makefile.in, so I cannot write the makefile.in.
Do you have the makefile.in?

I have searched for the answer for a week, but have not solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

this is the makefile from ffmpeg examples directory:

```
# use pkg-config for getting CFLAGS and LDLIBS
FFMPEG_LIBS=    libavdevice                        \
                libavformat                        \
                libavfilter                        \
                libavcodec                         \
                libswresample                      \
                libswscale                         \
                libavutil                          \

CFLAGS += -Wall -O2 -g
CFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --cflags $(FFMPEG_LIBS)) $(CFLAGS)
LDLIBS := $(shell pkg-config --libs $(FFMPEG_LIBS)) $(LDLIBS)

EXAMPLES=       decoding_encoding                  \
                demuxing                           \
                filtering_video                    \
                filtering_audio                    \
                metadata                           \
                muxing                             \
                scaling_video                      \

OBJS=$(addsuffix .o,$(EXAMPLES))

# the following examples make explicit use of the math library
decoding_encoding: LDLIBS += -lm
muxing:            LDLIBS += -lm

.phony: all clean-test clean

all: $(OBJS) $(EXAMPLES)

clean-test:
    $(RM) test*.pgm test.h264 test.mp2 test.sw test.mpg

clean: clean-test
    $(RM) $(EXAMPLES) $(OBJS)
```

as you can see it's a plain handwritten Makefile so there's no autotools stuff, and you can change it easily